# How to send text from stdin to a script

Tags: c, linux, unix, redirect, stdin

Other than doing:

```
$ ./script < myfile.txt
```

Is there a way to pass text directly in the command-line, for example something like:

```
./script < "hello this is not a test"
```

The program I have which I want to send text to is:

```
// script.c
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     char c;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
         putchar(c);
 }
```

Comment: @costaparas yes, so basically just use `<<<` instead of `<` above, correct?

Comment: That's one way, but its not portable. You could use it, but I'd recommend the `echo` example shown in the accepted answer (or even better `printf`).

Comment: The pipe method works on Windows, too.